# Using a variable to access hash keys in Template Toolkit

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I have an array whose contents is

```
$VAR1 = {
'1' => 'May 05, 2011',
'0' => 'Jul 22, 2009',
'2' => 'Jun 13, 2012'
};
```

I am trying to display it in the catalyst template, the code is

```
[% x = 0 %]
[% FOREACH mortgage IN mortgages %]

<table width=40% border=1 cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td><b>[% dateformat.x %]</b></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
[% x = x+1 %]
[% END %]
```

The dateformat.x should display  May 05, 2011 or Jul 22, 2009 or Jun 13, 2012 according to the value of x but the error is that it displays nothing. It shows a blank .

The error I think is that the key in the array is a string while the value of x that is used with the dateformat is numeric. If I add 0 or 1 with the dateformat then it displays correctly([% dateformat.0 %]).

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do and what goes wrong. Or even whether there is a problem at all, seeing how you only state that something is displayed correctly. May just be me, but personally i would suggest you rephrase your question if you want something answered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`[% dateformat.x %]` looks in the `dateformat` hash for a key of `x`. To tell template toolkit that `x` is a variable, prefix it with `$`:

```
[% dateformat.$x %]
```

> To access a hash entry using a key stored in another variable, prefix the key variable with '$' to have it interpolated before use (see [Variable Interpolation](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Variables.html#section_Variable_Interpolation)).

Answer (score 5):

I appreciate this question has already been asked and answered, but a handy alternative is the `item()` [VMethod](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/VMethods.html#section_item). This is particularly effective when you have hash keys that conflict with VMethods:

```
[%- SET myhash = { last => 'Blues', first => 'Elwood',
                   address => '1060 West Addison', city => 'Chicago' };
    myhash.first; # doesn't do what you want,
                  # because first is a VMethod for 1st element in an array
    myhash.item('first'); # displays "Elwood"
-%]
```

VMethods like `first`, `last`, `size` and `sort` are common traps for the unwary here.

Comment: I upvoted you  particularly for a way how to declare a hash variable inside Template Toolkit, as I was searching for that and I ended up here.